# SecurityException when creating new FileInfo on Rackspace

Tags: c#, asp.net, rackspace, cloudfiles

I'm getting the following exception when uploading a file to Rackspace Cloud Files:

> Security Exception
>   **Description**: The application attempted to perform an operation not
>   allowed by the security policy.  To
>   grant this application the required
>   permission please contact your system
>   administrator or change the
>   application's trust level in the
>   configuration file.
>
> **Exception Details**: System.Security.SecurityException:
>   Request for the permission of type
>   'System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission,
>   mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
>   failed

It seems to only happen with this file.

It is happening in a method where I check for a unique file name and I can't seem to figure out why.

```
    private string GetUniqueStorageItemName(string storageItemName)
    {
        int count = 0;
        string Name = "";


        if (cloudConnection.GetContainerItemList(Container).Contains(storageItemName))
        {
            System.IO.FileInfo f = new System.IO.FileInfo(storageItemName); // error on this line
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(f.Extension))
            {
                Name = f.Name.Substring(0, f.Name.LastIndexOf('.'));
            }
            else
            {
                Name = f.Name;
            }

            while (cloudConnection.GetContainerItemList(Container).Contains(storageItemName))
            {
                count++;
                storageItemName = Name + count.ToString() + f.Extension;
            }
        }

        return storageItemName;
    }
```

Comment: Ok, sometimes just posting the question helps bring light to the issue. The file already exists on the server....
I suppose the question here is 'why can't I use FileInfo' or 'do I really need to use it - I think I can get around it'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working around using FileInfo. Changed the code to the following. Is this the best solution?

```
            if(storageItemName.Contains('.'))
            {
                Name = storageItemName.Substring(0, storageItemName.LastIndexOf('.'));
                Ext = storageItemName.Substring(storageItemName.LastIndexOf('.'), storageItemName.Length - storageItemName.LastIndexOf('.'));
            }
            else
                Name = storageItemName;
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your application is running at Medium Trust or lower. Take a look at this blog post about Trust Levels and how you *might* be able to change them...it depends on how Rackspace configures things:

[ASP.NET trust levels demystified](http://codebetter.com/blogs/jeffrey.palermo/archive/2005/07/05/128845.aspx)

Comment: thanks, tried that and got an error that I cannot change the trust level due to inherited settings.

Comment: @senloe - That's what I figured would happen. When in hosted environments, it's typical that you can't access the File System directly (since it's often a shared environment).